# Relative Dynamic Loading with systemJS, using ES6/Babel syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, systemjs

I have a module written in pure ES6 that I would like to leverage in a separate web application. The module's entry point is main.js and contains the following:

**main.js**

```
export { A } from './a';
export { B } from './b';
export { C } from './c';
```

When I use systemJS to import this `main.js`, it then attempts to resolve these dependencies local to the web application, not the module.

> GET http://localhost:9000/dist/a.js 404 (Not Found)

I see there's support for [relative dynamic loading](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/wiki/Relative-Dynamic-Loading) already, but it involves passing an extra function to the `System.import` function, which I'm not using--I'm using ES6 syntax.

Are there any examples or best practices of how to do this? Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method for this is to hack* your `config.js` file. We need to register a new 'repository' with systemjs that points to the location of the library of the file system. To do this, we add the following line to our `config.js`.

```
System.config({
  "map": {
    ...
    "lib": "path/to/lib/main"
    ...
  }
});
```

When systemjs tries to load `lib`, it finds the map entry and loads all dependencies of `lib` relative to that location. If the library is in an unreasonably distant location, it may be useful to create a directory symlink in your application to the library.